# Title Format ruining itemize spacing

Tags: macros, spacing, formatting, titlesec, format

I use title format to change the look of my section commands and so on, after making a new section for some reason the spacing used by itemize is being ruined and it is not leaving the proper amount of white space. Ive left a picture of what I'm talking about below and the code needed to recreate it. Any help fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
%Packages 
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{titling}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}


\definecolor{r}{rgb}{0.9,.3,.5}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{thrm}{Theorem}%
{enhanced, breakable,
colback=r!7, colbacktitle=r!17, coltitle=RedViolet,
frame hidden, parbox=false,
arc=1.85pt, titlerule=0pt, toptitle=2pt, bottomtitle=2pt,
fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign= : \hspace{0.005cm},
segmentation style={solid, draw=r!55, line width=1pt}}{th}
%\begin{thrm}{Rank-Nullity Theorem}{env}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\LARGE}{\fbox{\thesection}}{12pt}{}

\begin{document}
    test
\chapter{awd}

\section{adww}
\begin{thrm}{w}{w}
woluygfouyesgvfuyesvfkluYSv
\begin{itemize}
  \item awd   
  \item dwa
\end{itemize}
\end{thrm}

\begin{thrm}{w}{w}
  woluygfouyesgvfuyesvfkluYSv
  \begin{itemize}
    \item awd   
    \item dwa
  \end{itemize}
  \end{thrm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set `\@nobreakfalse` at the beginning of the environment. If the `thrm` environment directly follows a sectional title, `\if@nobreak` returns true and this has the bad effect on the inner `itemize`.

```
\documentclass{book}
%Packages 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\definecolor{r}{rgb}{0.9,.3,.5}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{thrm}{Theorem}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  colback=r!7,
  colbacktitle=r!17,
  coltitle=RedViolet,
  frame hidden,
  parbox=false,
  arc=1.85pt,
  titlerule=0pt,
  toptitle=2pt,
  bottomtitle=2pt,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  separator sign={ : },
  segmentation style={solid, draw=r!55, line width=1pt},
  before upper=\csname @nobreakfalse\endcsname
}{th}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\LARGE}{\fbox{\thesection}}{12pt}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{awd}

\section{adww}
\begin{thrm}{w}{A}
woluygfouyesgvfuyesvfkluYSv
\begin{itemize}
  \item awd   
  \item dwa
\end{itemize}
\end{thrm}

\begin{thrm}{w}{B}
  woluygfouyesgvfuyesvfkluYSv
  \begin{itemize}
    \item awd   
    \item dwa
  \end{itemize}
  \end{thrm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! Any way I can generalize this to chapter, subsection levels?

Comment: Update this seems like it may already be generalized to other section levels, would you be able to confirm that?

Comment: @xyz04 It should work with every level.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but if You add something after section command like this:

```
\section{adww}
    
    \textcolor{r}{text}\\
    \color{r}
    \rule{\textwidth}{4pt}
    \color{black}
    text
```

or simply this:

```
\section{adww}
    
    text
```

You dont have any trouble on vertical spacing.

With the correction proposed You ha what requested:

[image]

Comment: I do know that this is an option, but the purpose of asking the question was to find a possible solution so I can circumnavigate this option.